# setTimeout in NodeJS /Express throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typeerror, settimeout

I have the following basic express route in nodejs:

```
app.get('/timeout', function (req, res) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout');
    }, 2000);

    res.send({ hello: "world" });
  });
```

It doesn't work, it throws an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
> at setTimeout (/Users/myproject/node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/src/classes/mail-service.js:58:10)
> at /Users/myproject/router.js:87:7

I don't understand why? I have tried not doing a `console.log`, I tried arrow functions, async await, not sending `res.send`. What client is meant here?

The other thing that confuses me is that the first line of the error  mentions a sendgrid module -which I do have installed, but which I'm not using in this route at all- : `at setTimeout (/Users/myproject/node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/src/classes/mail-service.js:58:10)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm so sorry, I found the error! My VS-Code *auto-imported* a setTimeout function from sendgrid. This is not the standard setTimeout function, so it threw an error. Didn't see it imported this automatically.

```
const { setTimeout } = require('@sendgrid/mail');
```